# C++ and Swift: Cannot invoke 'externalMethodName' with an argument list of '(Int)'

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c++

I was struggling building a swift app which uses a self written C++ class.
I got it to work with the needed Objective-C++ wrapper but now I'm currently having the problem, that I cannot call an external method with an int parameter. Obscurely it works with a pure number.

Example below:

Snippet from Swift class:

```
let validNumber = 5
let refScen = CppToObjCWrapper()
let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(validNumber!)
```

The corresponding wrapper method in CppToObjCWrapper.mm:

```
-(float)getCalcLoad:(int)value {
  RefScenLibCpp refScen;
  NSLog(@"Inside Wrapper. Value received: %d", value);
  return refScen.getCalcLoad(value);
}
```

And the C++ method in RefScenLibCpp.cpp:

```
float RefScenLibCpp::getCalcLoad(int value) {
  return result / 255 * 100;
}
```

As I said, if I try to call this method from the swift class it throws the error:

> Cannot invoke 'getCalcLoad' with an argument list of '(Int)'

But if I call the method from the Swift class with just a number like:

```
let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(42)
```

It works fine! I was searching for this problem a great amount of time now, but as I am working with Objective-C++ and C++ I don't think I found the right answer yet. Different approaches with (non-)optionals were not helpful. What confuses me even more, is the fact, that I have a similar C++ method that takes a String parameter and that I call just like the one with the int parameter, but this one works totally fine. I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To demonstrate the problem, I have recreated the error in a Swift playground with a minimal example:

```
func aFuncTakingInt32(val: Int32) {
    // do stuff
}

let validNumber = 42

aFuncTakingInt32(validNumber)
```

This code generates the same error:

> Cannot invoke 'aFuncTakingInt32' with an argument list of type '(Int)'

If we change `validNumber`'s type to explicitly be `Int32`:

```
let validNumber: Int32 = 42
```

Or if we construct an `Int32` out of the `Int` when we call the function:

```
aFuncTakingInt32(Int32(validNumber))
```

The error goes away and the code runs perfectly fine.

---

As an additional helpful detail to solving this problem, since the method we're trying to use is not defined in Swift, but instead in an Objective-C++ file we're importing, there *IS* a way to find out exactly what types of arguments the function expects on the Swift end of things.  If you type the method name out, and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and click the method name, you'll get some useful information:

[image]

Now we can see the *explicit* type that Swift expects to be passing to that method.  Here, it is clearly marked as an `Int32` variable (which we already knew since we just wrote that method in Swift).  This can be very useful when we don't have access to the source code or when we're not sure how Swift is translating code from one language into Swift.

---

Swift's `Int` type is different from the `int` primitive from Objective-C, C, C++, and many other languages.  Swift's `Int` is more similar to Objective-C's `NSInteger`.

If we tried passing Objective-C's `NSInteger` to this C++ method, it would compile but it would probably generate a warning (versus Swift's error).  That's because Objective-C is far less strict and is willing to do some implicit casting on primitives.

With that said, Swift has a handful of types that are more equivalent to C, C++, and Objective-C's `int` (and the other sizes of integers).  Here, we most likely want `Int32`.

The reason we can use `let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(42)` is because while `42` is a literal that by default will be interpreted as an `Int` (as we see in the `let validNumber = 42`), it can also be interpreted as many other numeric types, including `Int32` (and even floating point types).

However, when we do the following:

> ```
> let validNumber = 42
> ```

Here, `validNumber` must implicitly infer an explicit type.  And the type it is inferring is `Int` (which is different from Objective-C, C, & C++'s `int`).

So when we try the following:

> ```
> let validNumber = 42
> let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(validNumber)
> ```

We're trying to pass an `Int` to a method that expect an `Int32`, and because Swift is very, very strict about the types of the parameters it lets us pass, it generates an error (where Objective-C would potentially generate a warning).

We should be able to fix this by explicitly declaring `validNumber`'s type as the appropriate, `Int32`:

```
let validNumber: Int32 = 42
let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(validNumber)
```

But additionally, if it doesn't make sense on the Swift end to keep this variable's type as an `Int32`, we *can* construct an `Int32` out of an `Int`, so we can do something like this:

```
let validNumber = 42
let result = refScen.getCalcLoad(Int32(validNumber))
```

---

As an additional caveat, we don't run into this problem with a `String` because Objective-C's `NSString` maps to Swift's `String`.  We also wouldn't run into this problem with `char` which maps to Swift's `Character` or `bool` which maps to Swift's `Bool`.

Comment: Make sure to make note of my comments about Alt-Clicking.  It'll prove useful to you in the future.